# python Webscrape requests vs selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I am not really clear about the response I am getting here. It looks incomplete. I was wondering if this is the wrong approach and should switch to selenium. I am trying to get all the menu items along with the prices and the addons here. I was just checking the response. Any guidance would be immensely helpful. Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/v4/full?lat=12.9715987&lng=77.5945627&menuId=41100'
page = requests.get(url).json()
for k, v in page.items():
    print(v)
```

Comment: On first view not a question of `request` vs `selenium` - Could you improve your question and provide your expected output, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/v4/full?lat=12.9715987&lng=77.5945627&menuId=41100'
page = requests.get(url).json()
menu_items = page["data"]["menu"]["items"]

for k, v in menu_items.items():
    print("Name: {}".format(v["name"]))
    print("Description: {}".format(v["description"]))
    print("Price: {}".format(v["price"]))
    if "addons" in v.keys():
        for i in v["addons"]:
            print("\t{}".format(i["group_name"]))
            for j in i["choices"]:
                print("\t\tName: {}".format(j["name"]))
                print("\t\tPrice: {}".format(j["price"]))
                print()
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just one question. Can I get the dish's description, I think I saw it in the response. It's just that I am not very good with `json` .

Comment: By the way the 'page' variable is just a nested dict.

Answer (score 1):

**What is going on?**

Think it is not a question of `request` vs `selenium` for web-scraping cause all that you are doing is requesting an api and getting a `json` response.

And your code works fine the way it is written, but what you expect to do is something other, so you have to deal with iterating `dict` in another way.

This will do the trick:

```
page['data']['menu']['items'].items()
```

**Example**

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/v4/full?lat=12.9715987&lng=77.5945627&menuId=41100'
page = requests.get(url).json()

for k, v in page['data']['menu']['items'].items():
    print(v)
```

**Output**

```
{'id': 8194821, 'name': 'Egg Omelette', 'category': 'Quick Bites', 'description': '', 'cloudinaryImageId': '', 'recommended': 0, 'inStock': 0, 'isVeg': 0, 'enabled': 1, 'displayOrder': 0, 'price': 8500, 'variants_new': {'exclude_list': [], 'variant_groups': []}, 'addons': [{'group_id': 21778839, 'group_name': 'Addons', 'choices': [{'id': 17471659, 'name': 'Watermelon Juice', 'price': 10000, 'inStock': 0, 'isVeg': 1, 'order': 1, 'default': 0}, {'id': 17471658, 'name': 'Coke (750 ml)', 'price': 6000, 'inStock': 1, 'isVeg': 1, 'order': 1, 'default': 0}], 'maxAddons': -1, 'maxFreeAddons': -1, 'minAddons': 0, 'order': 1}, {'group_id': 21778838, 'group_name': 'Beverage Addons', 'choices': [{'id': 17471658, 'name': 'Coke (750 ml)', 'price': 6000, 'inStock': 1, 'isVeg': 1, 'order': 1, 'default': 0}], 'maxAddons': -1, 'maxFreeAddons': -1, 'minAddons': 0, 'order': 1}], 'cropChoices': 2, 'itemScore': 0, 'itemDiscount': 0, 'isPopular': 0, 'restId': '41100', 'showMC': 0, 'ribbon': {'text': 'Must Try', 'textColor': '#ffffff', 'topBackgroundColor': '#d53d4c', 'bottomBackgroundColor': '#b02331'}, 'attributes': {'portionSize': '', 'vegClassifier': 'EGG', 'accompaniments': ''}, 'itemNudgeType': ''}
{'id': 8194822, 'name': 'Paneer Sholey', 'category': 'Starters', 'description': 'Fried cottage cheese cubes, tossed in signature spices & curry leaves garnish.', 'cloudinaryImageId': '', 'recommended': 0, 'inStock': 0, 'isVeg': 1, 'enabled': 1, 'displayOrder': 0, 'price': 22000, 'variants_new': {'exclude_list': [], 'variant_groups': []}, 'cropChoices': 2, 'itemScore': 0, 'itemDiscount': 0, 'isPopular': 0, 'restId': '41100', 'showMC': 0, 'attributes': {'portionSize': '', 'vegClassifier': 'VEG', 'accompaniments': ''}, 'itemNudgeType': ''}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you could just glance at the answer above. I 'm kind of looking for that just with the Dish's description. I am weak with `json`. Much Appreciated,

Comment: To get only the description do that: `print(v.get('description'))` instead of `print(v)`

Comment: returns `None` ..Do we use `get`?

Comment: This worked. ` print("Description: {}".format(v["description"]))`

Comment: You can use both, it dependce what you have done before :`for k,v in page['data']['menu']['items'].items():
    print(v['description'])`

Comment: Ah!..Thanks for the info. I can only accept 1 answer, else I would have accepted both. Yours and the other helped me lot in understanding how to get elements inside of these dicts. Upvoted!.Thanks Again.

Comment: For dealing with json and trying to find a value for a key that’s buried down in multiple levels of nesting, checkout this link. There’s a nice code snippet half way down the page for locating a key's value no matter how deeply nested. https://hackersandslackers.com/extract-data-from-complex-json-python/

Although careful of duplicate keys cause it will return values for all of them. It’s also not ideal to be passing a whole page through it speed wise, so if you can extract one of the lower nested levels closer to where you think the key is, it will be faster.